# use of removeif for filtering list containing objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am stuck on using removeif java 8 and looking for some help

```
List<ACHTransaction> transactions = transactionDao.retrieveTransactions(getJobParameters();
```

from transactions I want to remove those transactions based on checking property of object

if transaction.getFileHash is not null then I want to remove that transaction. if transaction.getFileHash is null I want to keep it.

so I am trying removeif

```
List<ACHTransaction> transactions = transactionDao.retrieveTransactions(getJobParameters().removeIf(t -> (Optional.ofNullable(t.getFileHash()).orElse(0).intValue() != 0));
```

but I am getting errors. Is someone can explain how removeif work with object properties?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Incompatible type Required ACHTransaction Found boolean

Comment: `removeIf` modifies the collection you’re invoking it on and returns a `boolean` telling you whether it did modify the collection, i.e. if there was any matching element. You can’t assign that `boolean` to a `List`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can retrieve the list and then remove the elements with `removeIf`:

```
List<ACHTransaction> transactions =
    transactionDao.retrieveTransactions(getJobParameters());

transactions.removeIf(t -> t.getFileHash() != null);
```

Or you can do as in your own answer and use a stream:

```
List<ACHTransaction> transactions =
    transactionDao.retrieveTransactions(getJobParameters()).stream()
        .filter(t -> t.getFileHash() == null)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: t is nullable that is a reason I was using optional

Comment: @Satya Yes, `t` is nullable, but this doesn't mean that you must use `Optional` whenever you see a `null` value. You should always try to write code that is easy to read and understand. `Optional` is meant to be used as a return type in methods.

Comment: Yes you are correct. In my case I don't own the other code to correct the design issue. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I tested below piece of code and it worked as required. I hope this is what you were looking for.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestRemoveIf {



public static void main(String[] args) {

    Transaction myTrans1 = new Transaction("myTrans1");
    Transaction myTrans2 = new Transaction("myTrans2");
    Transaction myTrans3 = new Transaction("myTrans3");
    Transaction myTrans4 = new Transaction("myTrans4");

    myTrans1.setFileHash("not Null");
    myTrans3.setFileHash("not null");

    List<Transaction> trList = new ArrayList();
    trList.add(myTrans1);
    trList.add(myTrans2);
    trList.add(myTrans3);
    trList.add(myTrans4);

    trList.removeIf(t -> t.getFileHash()!=null);

    System.out.println(trList);


}


}


public class Transaction {

String fileHash;
String name;

public String getFileHash() {
    return fileHash;
}

public void setFileHash(String fileHash) {
    this.fileHash = fileHash;
}

public Transaction(String name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Transaction [fileHash=" + fileHash + ", name=" + name + "]";
}



}
```

Answer (score -1):

At present I solved it like

```
List<ACHTransaction> transactions =
        achManagementDao
            .retrieveTransactions(getJobParameters())
            .stream()
            .filter(t -> !(Optional.ofNullable(t.getFileHash()).orElse(0).intValue() == 0))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but please let me know if there is better way

Comment: Using that `Optional` inside the `filter` operation doesn't make any sense. It's far from being readable code, and the poor soul that will have to maintain it will have a hard time trying to figure out your intentions. It would be much better to just use `filter(t -> t.getFileHash() == null)`.

Answer (score -1):

```
List<ACHTransaction> transactions =
    transactionDao.retrieveTransactions(getJobParameters());

Predicate<ACHTransaction> cond = (t -> Objects.nonNull(t.getFileHash())));

transactions.removeIf(cond);
```